# why can't i get the button element? and I've tried various ways to get it

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I'm so exhausted I've tried many ways to get selected but everything I've tried failed.
code html `<button class="sc-nkuzb1-0 sc-d5trka-0 dsOMxw button" data-theme="home.verifyButton">Authenticate</button>`

and i have tried starting from await page.$x, $, $$, waitForSelector or waitForXPath but nothing works and my code
`

```
await Promise.all([
    await page.waitForSelector('#root > div > div.sc-99cwso-0.sc-11w6f91-0.fcBZbp.eWRcSj.home.box.screen > button'),
    await page.waitForSelector('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/button'),
    await page.waitForSelector('button[data-theme="home.verifyButton"]'),
    await page.waitForSelector('//button[contains(., "Authenticate")]'),
    await page.waitForSelector('.sc-nkuzb1-0.sc-d5trka-0.dsOMxw.button') 
  ]);
```

so where is my mistake?`

i'm trying to be able to click on the button element of puppeteer but i never succeed when i try

Comment: Remove all `await`s except the one before `Promise.all`

Comment: await Promise.all([
    await page.waitForSelector('#root > div > div.sc-99cwso-0.sc-11w6f91-0.fcBZbp.eWRcSj.home.box.screen > button'),
         page.waitForSelector('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/button'),
         page.waitForSelector('button[data-theme="home.verifyButton"]')
  ]); like this?

Comment: Please share the actual site. Some of those selectors should work, but perhaps the element is in shadow DOM or an iframe, the element isn't in the viewport, or you're being blocked as a robot. And yes, when you `await` each `page.waitForSelector` call, it blocks for those promises to resolve serially rather than in parallel. The `Promise.all` is pointless here because everything is resolved by the time it runs. For that to work, you need to pass promises to it, not the `await`ed results of those promises.

Comment: this one looks good: `await page.waitForSelector('button[data-theme="home.verifyButton"]')` if it doesn't work it's either not there yet or in an iframe

Comment: I've tried adding await page.waitForNavigation
 but still no luck

Comment: I'm trying on the site https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup in the Authenticate your account section @ggorlen